# Нужны знаки за места в чартах

Tags: предложение, нытьё, знаки

**Причина создания запроса:**

Я попал на первое место за неделю и на первую страницу за всё время. А знаков за это нема... Это меня расстраивает и поэтому тут будет метка [нытьё](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%91) .

**Что предлагаю:**

Если есть возможность создавать новые знаки, то было б хорошо получать их за продвижение по чартам. Например: `целый месяц на первом месте в неделю`, `в десятке по итогам года`, `обогнал @Vlad по очкам в недельном чарте`.

**Обоснование полезности:**

Погоня за подобными знаками повысит активность пользователей и пойдёт на пользу сообществу увеличив дух соревновательности.

Comment: Кстати, в предпросмотре вопроса текст `[meta-tag:«нытьё»]` отобразилось как следует, а в опубликованном вопросе - как видите  - не преобразовалось. Баг!

Comment: С меткой дело было в кавычках вокруг названия метки. А в справке поформатированию - пример с кавычками. И они работают в предпросмотре.

Comment: Кстати, поздравляю. Бедж или нет, нет так важно.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо! =) Нашёлся таки добрый человек на сайте))

Answer (score 6):

Знаки спроектированы так, чтобы для их получения у всех были равные шансы и участники не блокировали получение знаков другими участниками. В предлагаемой вами механике знак будет доставаться всегда только одному или нескольким топовым участникам. Остальные будут вечно фрустрированы, что не очень хорошо с точки зрения геймификации.

Более того, во многих случаях знак будет каждый раз доставаться одному и тому же <s>игроку</s> участнику. Например, по метке С# всегда будет первым Jon Skeet, а 
целый месяц на первом месте в неделю большей частью достанется Gordon Linoff. Это ещё больше огорчит остальных участников и может спровоцировать их на претензии вроде «ну что ты каждый раз забираешь первое место, иди уже отдохни от сайта, дай другим заработать знак».

*«обогнал @Vlad по очкам в недельном чарте»* – это спровоцирует кого-нибудь украсть Vlad, чтобы он не отвечал на вопросы пару недель.

Знаки сделаны для того, чтобы поддерживать *хорошие* действия на сайте, но не *лучшие*. Лучшее – враг хорошего. =)

А для поощрения стремления быть лучшим уже есть цепочка Mortarboard/<s>Академик</s> Чемпион + Epic/<s>Эпопея</s> Герой + Legendary/Легенда. Эти знаки как раз не подвержены взаимному блокированию участников.

Comment: А если так: "Занял первое место ... среди тех, кто ещё не получал этот знак"?

Comment: Да, давайте тогда отсеивать уже получивших - можно значки за обгон в чартах тех, кто ещё значка не получил, при минимальноо необходимой общей репутации. Ну или за резкое изменение позиции в чарте - типа `поднялся на 50 мест за год`. Последний вариант как раз топовые участники получить никак уже не смогут)

Comment: Ну или хотя бы значки за месячное место по ответам по метке. Типа - `лучший за месяц по Android` Некоторые метки имеют мало вопросов и по ним подняться совсем не сложно. Отвечающим будет выгода ставить больше меток под вопросы.